# Create nice skeleton for app with Express, Socket.IO and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am new guy in making "Javascript only" apps and I need help to start. I know, there is not any standard how to develop there apps but I need start clear and good.

I am planning to develop SPA React app with Socket.IO and API connections to server. I want server to be Express and Socket.IO

I found many tutorials but all of them, are just `create-react-app` installation and then making simple `server.js` file from server. But I want something like `express-generator` style (Routes and nice skeleton on server, too).

I also want to include Socket.Io server into my express app and make it routed too, so I will not end with `app.js` spammed with `io.on(` functions...

Can someone give me tips how to make skeleton for my app to make my life easier?

Comment: Udemy has a course that covers the express and socket-io. https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-nodejs-developer-course-2/learn/v4/content. And they also have react course as well.

Comment: Sure but I am trying the best way to combine all together and create nice start point. No tutorials covers setup of all three things in nice structured way